# How do I dynamically adjust for text based on values of multipole columns and set as parameters in R markdown output pdf

Tags: r, loops, parameters, r-markdown

Note the YAML. I have the title and author refer to set parameters

```
---
title: "`r params$ID_NUM`"
classoption: landscape 
author: "`r params$first` `r params$last`"
date: "8/11/2021"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    html_document: default
 params:
  ID_NUM: 1
  first: MICHAEL
  last: DOUGLAS
---
```

The script below is able to output the pdf and provide me with the id number as a title. Where it does not work is it's not able to provide me the "author" portion with the corresponding name with id value. Do I do a nested for loop?

```
for (i in unique(df$id)) {

rmarkdown::render("Document.Rmd", 
                params = list(id_NUM = i),
                output_file=paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

if the dataset looks like this

```
id   first      last 
 1   Michael    Douglas
 2   Sean       Penn
 3   Kevin      Bacon
```

I would like the first pdf to show

```
ID1
Michael Douglas
```

the second to show

```
ID2 
Sean  Penn
```

and last.

```
ID3
Kevin Bacon
```

I can get the ID portion but I can't get the names.

Update::

```
purrr::walk(df,function(x){
 i<-df$id
 p<-df$first
 z<-df$last
 rmarkdown::render(
    "Document.Rmd",
    output_file=paste0(i, ".pdf"),
    params = list(id=i,first=p,last=z)
  )
 })
```

Tried with this script but did not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following will work.

```r
for (i in unique(df$id)) {
first <- df$first[df$id == i]
last <- df$last[df$id == i]

rmarkdown::render("Document.Rmd", 
                params = list(id_NUM = i, first = first, last = last),
                output_file=paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

The `params` values for `first` and `last` do not exist. By creating them, you should be able to get their values.